# Accessing an image from another class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a quick question. I am trying to set an image from another view controller. what am I doing wrong?

The main view controller:

//how I set up the pop view:

```
lazy var popUpView: PopViews = {
        let view = PopViews()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 24
        view.delegate = self
        return view
    }()
```

The call to pop view

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now()){
            self.handleShowPop()
        }
```

handleShowPop function:

```
@objc func handleShowPop(){
        view.addSubview(popUpView)

        let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "Test")!
    popUpView.imageView = UIImageView(image: image)


        popUpView.button.setTitle("View Our Menu2", for: .normal)

        popUpView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: -40).isActive = true
        popUpView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        popUpView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.width - 154).isActive = true
        popUpView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.width - 104).isActive = true

        popUpView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
        popUpView.alpha = 0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5){
            self.visualEffectView.alpha = 0.7
            self.popUpView.alpha = 1
            self.popUpView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }
    }
```

This is the PopViews class:

I can add the image here but I cannot access it from the first view controller

```
 class PopViews: UIView {

     var imageView: UIImageView = {


let img = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "test"))
            img.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            img.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
            img.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
            img.image = imgz

            return img
        }()
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem with code?

Comment: I don't understand this code. Where is `imgz` defined?

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I try to display the image, it is simply not there

Comment: @dasdom fixed there

Comment: In the "call to pop view" you create a new `PopViews` but don't add it to the view hierarchy. It will just be thrown away when the closure is done.

Comment: @Paulw11 it is adding other elements to the pop view just not the image. I just havent shown that part. should I add more code?

Comment: You have `let pop = ...` in that closure and then nothing else is done with it.  If something is done with it then yes, show that code

Comment: Again, the function you have added doesn't use the `pop` variable from the dispatch closure.  The view on which you have set `imgz` is just thrown away.  Did you mean to set `imgz` on `self.popUpView`?

Comment: @Paulw11 after reviewing the code, thats all that uses the pop variable. Again, the code works when creating another label and button in the PopViews class (for pop view) so the issue is the PopViews accessing the image I believe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210335/discussion-between-paulw11-and-mike).

Comment: @Paulw11 can you have a look at my last message in chat